# android web service insert database

Tags: android, sql, web-services, symfony, insert

I created a web site of travel with symfony2, I want to create mobile application using web services created in the web site, I get the data using jsonarry and jsonobject ,how I can insert data using my mobile application.
if there is good library.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Retrofit library, see below,

https://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: Its the fastest library for handling with server database.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

you need to use httpurlconnection . you need not use libray for further use but if you want to deserialize and serialize json use GSON .

Answer (score 0):

You can establish connection with web API's using [okhttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) and can parse json data using Gson library just add `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'` in your build.gradle and parse necessary using MVC method

Check this tutorial https://kylewbanks.com/blog/Tutorial-Android-Parsing-JSON-with-GSON